# Problem with opening and editing in a file

Tags: c, file, save, load, file-handling

So i have this assignment (first programming class i take), in which we need to add things to a shoppinglist, let the user save the list as a .txt file, close the program, load any file (by userinput which file to open) and then being able to edit in the loaded file. At the moment this is the two functions i got for saving the file and loading the file:

Save:

```
void saveList(struct ShoppingList* list)    //  Function that saves the list to a .txt file
{
    FILE* fileHandler;                      //  When the file is called we call "filehandler" (like a temp name)
    char input[20];                         
    input[0] = '\0';                        //  if the input array is empty, charachter 0 is the last one

    printf("Enter the name of the .txt file (without the '.txt') where you want to save your shoppinglist\n(If it doesn't exist already, the program will create it for you): ");
    scanf_s("%s", input, 20);               //  Takes input from the user, this will be the file that is created and the list saved to, will be stored in "input"

    fileHandler = fopen(input, "w");        //  filehandler will open and write to a file, with the name stored in "input"
    if (fileHandler == NULL)                //  If filehandler is NULL
    {
        printf("Error!\n");                 //  Probbably because it could not create the file.
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list->length; i++)  //  When filehandler is NOT NULL (more or less)
    {
        fprintf(fileHandler, "%s %0.2f %s\n", list->itemList[i].productName, list->itemList[i].amount, list->itemList[i].unit);
    }
    fclose(fileHandler);                    //  Close the file when we are done with it (save it).
}
```

And this is the current Load (which is where i have problems, will explain under the code):

```
void loadList(struct ShoppingList* list)    //  Function that can load a saved list from a .txt file
{
    FILE* fileHandler;
    char filename[100], c;

    printf("Enter the name of the file you want to open: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    fileHandler = fopen(filename, "r");            // Open file 
    if (fileHandler == NULL)
    {
        printf("File does not exist / The file cannot be opened \n");
        return;
    }

    while (fgets(filename, 100, fileHandler) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", filename);
    }

    fclose(fileHandler);                        //fileHandler is done and shuts the file down
    return 0;
}
```

I'm currently able to load the file that, the program prints it out, but then when i want to display the loaded file again (displaying the current items in the shoppinglist is a thing the user can do, can send that code if anyone thinks it's needed) it returns "the list is empty." which it should if the list would had been empty, but i just loaded in the file with the list?

Currently at the limit of my knowledge and are atm just hitting my head against it. Help appriciated.

Comment: Off-topic, but I hope no one is teaching you to put comments out to the right of your code like that - it makes reading the comments hard, and it makes changing the code even harder and more time-consuming.  If you change a line of code, now you have to waste time and effort reformatting the comment so it lines up again.  And if you have to delete a line, if the comment is relevant to more than one line you now have to reformat a lot of lines.  And given `char input[20];`, `//  An array that can hold 20 charachters` is worse than completely useless - the size obvious but it's in two places.

Comment: Where in your `loadList` do you think you are saving any of the read data? The `list` parameter is not even used once. Doesn't that seem odd to you as that is presumably where the data to be displayed will come from?